Grammar ambiguities in C#

The expression (A < B, C > D) is a tuple with two elements, each a comparison.

The expression (A<B,C> D, E) is a tuple with two elements, the first of which is a declaration expression.

The invocation M(A < B, C > D, E) has three arguments.


The above three statements are from C# language spec - Grammar ambiguities.
Need help to understand, why in (A < B, C > D), A < B, C > D is considered as two separate elements, in (A<B,C> D, E), A<B,C> D is considered as a single element, and in M(A < B, C > D, E), A < B, C > D is considered as two separate elements.

The interpretation of the expressions depends on the wider scope and whether A is a variable or a type A<,>.

The prose in the specification you linked (above the examples) explains this. What don't you understand about it?

All these expressions are context-dependent. There's no general meaning for all of them. So the first one may be a tuple-declaration, however it can also be a an argument-definition in a function, depending on where the expression occurs.

As a side note - In practice, this is where spacing can assist or hinder the reader disambiguate the code. IDEs providing syntax highlighting also help to reduce the cognitive load when coming across something like this that is potentially ambiguous

In the document that you linked there's an explanation for this case:
If a sequence of tokens can be parsed (in context) as a simple_name (§12.8.4), member_access (§12.8.7), or pointer_member_access (§23.6.3) ending with a type_argument_list (§8.4.2), the token immediately following the closing > token is examined, to see if it is

One of (  )  ]  }  :  ;  ,  .  ?  ==  !=  |  ^  &&  ||  &  [; or
One of the relational operators <  >  <=  >=  is as; or
A contextual query keyword appearing inside a query expression; or
In certain contexts, identifier is treated as a disambiguating token. Those contexts are where the sequence of tokens being disambiguated is immediately preceded by one of the keywords is, case or out, or arises while parsing the first element of a tuple literal (in which case the tokens are preceded by ( or : and the identifier is followed by a ,) or a subsequent element of a tuple literal.

If the following token is among this list, or an identifier in such a context, then the type_argument_list is retained as part of the simple_name, member_access or pointer_member-access and any other possible parse of the sequence of tokens is discarded. Otherwise, the type_argument_list is not considered to be part of the simple_name, member_access or pointer_member_access, even if there is no other possible parse of the sequence of tokens.
In case of (A<B,C> D, E) the D is an identifier, we're parsing the first element of a tuple (tokens are preceded by (), and the identifier is followed by ,, so it is treated like a single element.
In other cases either the identifier is not followed by , (case with (A < B, C > D)), or this is not the first element of a tuple (case with M(A < B, C > D, E)).

This is explained in the prose above the examples in the linked section of the specification. I will try to rewrite it in my own words so it is potentially more understandable.
Ambiguities arise when the parser sees a simple name that ends with some type arguments - like Foo<T1, T2>. The spec calls this a "sequence of tokens". The type arguments could be part of the simple name, or it could be something else entirely, like parts of a comparison expression. The question we are trying to answer is, are the type arguments actually part of the simple name?
The spec then says that the next token that comes after the "sequence of tokens" determines whether the answer is "yes it is part of the simple name" or "no it is something else".
For example, if the next token is one of those listed in the list,
(  )  ]  }  :  ;  ,  .  ?  ==  !=  |  ^  &&  ||  &  [ <  >  <=  >=  is as

then the answer is "yes".
In the 3 examples you gave, the next token are all identifiers. What does the spec say if the next token is an identifier? Well, the answer is "yes" only in some situations:

when the sequence of tokens is preceded by is, case, out
when the sequence of tokens is somewhere in the first element of a tuple, and all of the following

the sequence of tokens is preceded by ( or : (: as in the end of a tuple element name)
the identifier is followed by ,


when the sequence of tokens is not the first element of a tuple.


In all 3 cases, the next token is D, an identifier. In (A < B, C > D), D is not followed by ,, so the answer is "no, <B, C> is not part of the simple name A". A, B, C, D are all separate names for different things.
In (A<B,C> D, E), D is followed by ,, so the answer is "yes". A<B,C> is one name, identifying a type with two type arguments.
In the method call, D is not in a tuple at all, so the answer is "no".

(A < B, C > D)
A tuple of two booleans. Something like:
bool x = A < B;
bool y = C > D;
(bool, bool) z = (x, y);

(A<B,C> D, E)
A tuple of two values, D of generic type A<B,C> is being declared in-place. Something like:
A<B,C> D;
object E;
(A<B,C>, object) z = (D, E);

M(A < B, C > D, E)
A function call with three arguments. the first two being boolean expressions and a third value E.
bool x = A < B;
bool y = C > D;
var E = someValue();    
M(x, y, E);

